# How to get total row count while having top row filter

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a temporary table in my stored procedure and i am filling it will some select statement. At the end i have to select only a few top records to send to the UI.

Is there any way i can get to know the total records but select on top few records. Means if i have 2515 records but i am selecting only top 1000 but still can get to know the total count.

```
SELECT TOP (@ROWS) * 
FROM #tempMoveFinal 
WHERE case_id = @case_id 
ORDER BY last_update_date DESC, item_id
```

I tried putting all the records in another temp table without the top row clause and then selecting the total row count but it's making the search query slower.

Is there any in-build function which can be used for this case?

Comment: SQL Server 2008, 2012

Comment: Why not run 2 queries - one for the count, and one for the rows?

Comment: @ventsyv: Is that the best practice? I know that's the last solution  but still why run same thing two times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you mean like this:

```
with total as (
    select 
       count(*)         as TotalCount
    from #tempMoveFinal 
    WHERE case_id = @case_id 
)
SELECT TOP (@ROWS) * 
    ,total.TotalCount
FROM #tempMoveFinal 
CROSS JOIN total
WHERE case_id = @case_id 
ORDER BY last_update_date DESC, item_id
```

Comment: I am trying this but getting error - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: @user728630: The previous command must be terminated by a semicolon. Many developers precede the *with* by a semicolon out of habit like so: ";with ..."..

Comment: Thanks, just one concern that it will show total count for all the rows. Hope that's not a performance hit

Comment: @user728630: Unless you have tens of millions of rows, and assuming the existence of a clustered index, there will not be a problem. The optimizer makes use of the stored total Row Count from the statistics on the clustered index on every decision whether or not to use any index, so any overhead is free.

Comment: Thanks, just one last thing, if i want to assign the TotalCount value to a variable, how can i. Coz the compiler does not recognize 'total' when doing like this - SET @totalCount = (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM total)

Comment: @user728630: That's a new question. Post it and I will look at it.